# Force acting on two wires due to a rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

Here a rod of mass $M$ is hung with the help of two cylindrical wires marked with yellow and red colors. We know the weight of the rod is acting on the center of gravity of the rod(mid point of the rod). We had a question in our book for determining stress in the two wires. *So they reasoned that since $Mg$ is acting on the mid point and the two wires are at the end of the rod,the two wires will experience $Mg/2$ force each*. But i am not being able to digest this. I mean it seems to me that they see two wires,so they divide by $2$ which doesn't seem to be a sound logic to me. How can we determine the forces acting on the two wires? Is there any way to rigorously prove that both wires will experience $Mg/2$ force each?

Answer (score 0):

So on the midpoint of the rod, there is a force $Mg$. But we also know that the rod is not moving! This means that there should be forces counteracting it, since the sum of the forces on the rod should be zero! The only two other places where a force is at work on the rod, is where it is hung by the cylindrical wires. These are the span forces. So we easily find that the sum of the span forces should be $Mg$ as well, otherwise the rod would move. Because the system is symmetric right and left, both span forces should then be $Mg/2$. Is it clear now? :)

Answer (score 0):

For zero angular acceleration, the torques about an end of the rod should be zero:  TL – mg(L/2) = O. where T is the tension in one string.